# Ways to compose input components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, composition

I want to have a base-input component, then a number-input component that extends that, and a currency-input component that extends that.

By extend I was hoping to just have the 'child' component (in inheritence terms) use the parent component in its template since that seems to be the 'Vue way'.

But I want to be able to automatically support events etc without having to manually add handles for `@click`, `@blur`, `@keyup`, etc (or any other events that get added later)

Ideally I would like to be able to write:

```
<currency-input @click="clickMe"></currency-input>
```

and have the `currency-input` pick up the events of the input that's inside of it.

```
// baseInput.js

<template>
  <input v-on:click="">
</template>
```

I am also using masked-input in many of the inputs to help with consistent masking. I had a mixin, but that doesn't seem to allow me to change the markup to add the prop rendering. I'm wondering what the recommended way of doing this would be so that I can easily make different types of input components that always have default input functionality.

Comment: you can use [`click.native`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Listening-for-Native-Events-on-Components-with-v-on-changed)

Comment: @RoyJ could you give more example as to where? on the base component? I would still then have to set up each event type at each level of inheritance wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

[`click.native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) will listen on a component for a native event to bubble up from an element contained in the component. In your case, it would be

```
<currency-input @click.native="clickMe"></currency-input>
```